# Do all blackberries have some kind of support for email attachment addition of calendar appointments?

Tags: blackberry, calendar, bes

Does blackberry support the addition of appointments sent as attachments via email or MMS like the iCalendar format?

iCalendar (aka RFC 2445) has the file extension *.ics or *.vcs (v2.0, v1.0 respectively).  I cannot find a solid answer/evidence (E.G. RIM publication) as to whether, and to what degree, Blackberry supports this standard.

I created a [simple.ics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) file and sent it as a mail attachment to my blackberry.  I get error "This attachment type cannot be viewed on your device".  I also tried sending via MMS and following the procedure for [opening iCalendar files on the blackberry 9800](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/smartphone_users/deliverables/18577/Add_an_appt_to_your_calendar_from_a_text_msg_60_1052979_11.jsp).  I have a blackberry Tour (9630) and the procedure doesn't work for me.

If anyone has any solid documentation (not forum postings) with an answer that would be awesome.  I'm open to ideas/suggestions.  We do have a BES server.

Comment: We don't do cellphone support here.

Comment: Try http://www.howardforums.com

Comment: That's odd.  There's question tags for Blackberry and other posts regarding blackberry and BES...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this online, basically you want to modify the ICS file to work with your Blackberry as follows:

1. Download the ICS file to your PC
2. Edit the ICS file using a text editor and add METHOD:REQUEST (or replace METHOD:PUBLISH with METHOD:REQUEST)
3. Forward the modified ICS file to your blackberry.

Comment: I did happen to find that site as well http://forums.crackberry.com/f152/ics-calendar-attachment-workaround-237230/. Unfortunetly it didnt help. In fact, even a blank ICS file gives me the same error. I also tried sending via MMS as is documented by BB for the Torch 9800. This does not work at all on the Tour 9630 http://docs.blackberry.com/en/smartphone_users/deliverables/18577/Add_an_appt_to_your_calendar_from_a_text_msg_60_1052979_11.jsp